# Does clearing cache in at os level affect oracle running database?

Tags: linux, oracle-12c

I have 32 gb of ram for running Oracle 12c database. Now I am facing memory issue at OSlevel. 
Here are the details of `free -h`:

```
[oracle@sa1 df_size]$ free -h
total          used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G        1.2G        369M         22G         29G        7.7G
Swap:          2.0G        2.0G        9.3M
```

*If I clear buff/cache memory at OS level does it impact on Database ?*

To clear cache I will execute this command:

```
sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Comment: I do not see any issue. https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: ok  thanks@Balazs Papp . that means i can run this command at os level to clear cache in running database server, right ?

Comment: Doing that will drop the OS cache, but not the Oracle cache that lives in its own buffer cache (in its shared memory segment). Just a FYI, really

Comment: yes i know that @Philᵀᴹ , oracle has its own buffer cache. i am just simply to confirm this before doing the task .

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @mustaccio u can check my output of  **free -h**  i am facing memory issue . also checked there was big size consuming by  **buff/cache** . so i need to free that memory.